# Heroku deployment data not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Hello I am making an app which has two model Category and Doctor .. The purpose is to list all doctors .. The app is running perfectly in local server. But when I deploy it to Heroku the data are not showing. Is their any one who can help ?

Comment: add more details please are you getting any errors

Comment: No I am not getting any error .. when I am opening the app the the page is opening perfectly but the data are not their

Comment: Did you create the data or have you run the seed command

Comment: https://www.railstutorial.org/book i followed this book

Answer (score 2):

You can check the data inside your table through the console by running `heroku run rails c`

Then you can check if there is a data or not by `Category.count` and `Doctor.count`

If there is no data and you have it in the `seed.rb` , just run your seed by `heroku run rake db:seed`